# Calculo en spreadsheet de Google

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

estoy intentando hacer unos calculos en una hoja de calculo de Google pero no se como realizarlo.

Tengo una fecha inicio y una fecha fin con un precio mensual, quiero automatizar de alguna manera que si yo cambio el día de fin se me calculo los días totales y me haga la operación matemática para calcular los € totales en esos días.

Si la cuenta de los dias, lo hago de forma manual me salen unos precios que luego no me coinciden si lo hago mas automatico (Restando la fecha fin - la fecha inicio, el resultado lo saco en numero normal) El error esta o eso entiendo, que no coincide porque el mes de Febrero tiene menos dias y nosotros facturamos por día no por mes completo, por lo que no es lo mismo sacar el precio del día en Enero que en Febrero.

Me podéis ayudar como plantear esa casuistica?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Diego. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio. Tu preguntas es muy amplia ya que has de mostrar lo intentado y los errores concretos que te han surgido. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la función `DAYS()` que te muestra la diferencia de días entre dos fechas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo de el cálculo entre estas dos fechas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.